# Can't use External JS in angular 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular

I'm trying to integrate a html template in my angular project and everything is going fine except my JS plugins are not loading. I've given the path to the files in the `index.html` page. The styles are working fine.

index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Estate</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <!-- Google Font -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Css Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/elegant-icons.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/themify-icons.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/nice-select.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/jquery-ui.min.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/owl.carousel.min.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/magnific-popup.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/slicknav.min.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>

  <script src="assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.nice-select.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.slicknav.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can import your external JS files in Angular by mentioning them in **angular.json** file.

Inside angular.json you have to mention your files in **scripts** array. Make sure you are giving absolute path for the files that are present in the assets.

```
"scripts": [
              "../../../assets/jquery/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js",
              "../../../assets/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
            ]
```

Comment: Is not needed to import the js file in the component that is going to use it if it's added in the scripts section of the angular-cli.json.

Comment: If you need a reference of the file, you have to import it.

Comment: It's not true. Once you load the script in the scripts section it gets loaded in the memory. You need to import the file's reference only if you have to use something inside that script.